# Laravel send api JSON in search response

Tags: json, laravel, response

I have a search field to filter news, but I have no idea is this correct way to do.

```
<form method="GET" action="search" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input style="width:430px;" class="form-control py-2" type="search" name="search" value="Buscar Noticia" id="buscar" onclick='javascript: this.value = ""'>
  <span class="input-group-append">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </button>
  </span>
```

This is my NoticiaResource:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $filtro = $request->get('search');

    if(!empty($filtro))
    {
        $noticias = Noticia::where('titulo', 'LIKE', '%' .$filtro . '%')->paginate(4);   
    } 
    else
    {
        $noticias = Noticia::all();    
    }

    return $noticias->toArray();
}
```

The NoticiasController:

```
public function show(Noticia $noticias)
{
    NoticiaResource::withoutWrapping();
    return new NoticiaResource($noticias);
}
```

Add api route in api.php:

```
Route::get('noticias', 'NoticiasController@show');
```

And route to return same url in web.php:

```
Route::get('search', function(Request $request){
    return redirect('noticias.html');
})->name('search');
```

Problem is JSON always return all news, don't filter anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try `public function toArray(Request $request)` [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests)

Comment: Now don't show nothing, I applied global directive "use Request" also no work with "use Illuminate\Http\Request;"

Comment: It's a bit weirdly written. Why do you want to open this function in the function?  public function toArray($request)
{
    ...

    return $noticias->toArray();
}

Comment: Just to build JSON, work fine, but problem is filter news, always show entire news in database.

Comment: I changed: return $noticias->toArray(); by return json_decode($noticias); but still no work

Comment: Check this onclick='javascript: this.value = ""'.. what does it do?

Comment: When click on input, erase default value "Buscar Noticia". I checked request in route and return value inside input, I think problem is on resource controller but no idea how to do to get api from it.